# ABAddressBook changes listener

Tags: objective-c, abaddressbook

Is there a way to be notified when the addressbook is being changed?
i.e. When a user is editing a contact phone number.

The reason I ask this is because my app has a contacts table of its own from users I pull out of the addressBook. I want to know when to update their data without doing so every time the app awakens.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to do what you do but I can give you an important tip when you check your address book against a local copy (e.g. core data):

There is a unique ID (`ABRecordID`) assigned to any contact which changes. Don't rely on that. From the Apple doc:

> **Using Record Identifiers**
>
> Every record in the Address Book database has a unique record
> identifier. This identifier always refers to the same record, unless
> that record is deleted or the data is reset. Record identifiers can be
> safely passed between threads. They are not guaranteed to remain the
> same across devices.
>
> The recommended way to keep a long-term reference to a particular
> record is to store the first and last name, or a hash of the first and
> last name, in addition to the identifier. When you look up a record by
> ID, compare the record’s name to your stored name. If they don’t
> match, use the stored name to find the record, and store the new ID
> for the record.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/DirectInteraction.html